# Distribution of $Y = 1/X$ when $X\sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta). $

Tags: probability, distributions, self-study

Suppose $X\sim \text{Gamma}(\alpha, \beta). $ Determine the distribution of $Y = 1/X.$

This is what I reached as a solution: the distribution of $Y = 1/X$ is a gamma distribution with shape parameter $\alpha+1$ and scale parameter $1/(\beta\cdot y).$

Comment: Hint:  https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/277567/variation-on-inverse-gamma-1-xr-inv-gamma

Comment: Note that your scale parameter is a function of $y$, so it isn't a parameter at all!

Comment: I have added the [tag:self-study] tag. From future, please do the same for homework problems by yourself. Also, whatever the attempt is, you should show so that the community may identify the mistake other wise this question is meaningless.

Answer (score 3):

With
$$
Y = 1/X \overset{X >0}{\iff} X = 1/Y, \\
\frac{\mathrm d \, 1/y}{\mathrm d \, y} = -\frac{1}{y^2},
$$
and using the [shape-rate parameterization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_distribution#Characterization_using_shape_%CE%B1_and_rate_%CE%B2), a [change of variables](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Probability_density_function#Scalar_to_scalar) yields
$$
\begin{align}
\mathop{f_Y}\left(y\right) 
&= \mathop{\text{Gamma}}\left(\frac 1 y;\alpha, \beta\right) \cdot \left| \frac{\mathrm d \, 1/y}{\mathrm d \, y} \right| \\
&= 
\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\mathop{\Gamma}\left(\alpha\right)} \left(\frac 1 y\right)^{\alpha -1} \exp\left(-\beta \cdot \frac 1 y\right) \cdot \left|-\frac{1}{y^2}\right| \\
&= 
\frac{\beta^\alpha}{\mathop{\Gamma}\left(\alpha\right)} y^{-\alpha - 1} \exp\left(-\frac \beta y\right) \;\; \forall \, y \in \mathbb{R}_{>0}
\end{align}
$$
for the probability density function $\mathop{f_Y}$ of $Y$.

What distribution does $\mathop{f_Y}$ correspond to?

Comment: Added a minor format change, if you don't mind. +1.

Comment: @User1865345 Why didn't you like the version with $1/y$ in the numerator?

Comment: I neither disliked it, nor it was wrong - just that the latter version is more clear in what the differential operator is working on. But again you can rollback if you want :-)

Comment: @User1865345 I think in this case it's really a matter of taste, so rolled back. But I appreciate the effort you put into formatting so many old and new posts!

Comment: Not a problem! Appreciate your feedback and posts.